# "fn is not a function" discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

recently I'm having some problems in Discord.js. I'm not an exper so forgive me if I ask some stuid question. This is the code:

```
let rUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]));
if(!rUser) return message.channel.send('Couldn\'t find this user!');
let rReason = args.join(' ').slice(22);
if(!rReason) return message.channel.send('Insert a reason');

let reportEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription('**User report**')
.addField('Reported user:', `${rUser.displayName} <${rUser.id}>`)
.addField(`Reason:`, `${rReason}`)
.addField('Reported by:', message.author.username)
.setColor(0xf52c2c);

let rChannel = client.channels.cache.get(707956253040574525)
if(!rChannel) return message.channel.send('Not valid report channel');

rChannel.send(reportEmbed)
```

It gives me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

I'm using: node.js (6.14.4), discord.js (12.2.0), ms (2.1.2)

EDIT

Resolved updating node.js and changing

```
let rChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(`name`, 'reports')
```

with

```
let rChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'reports')
```

where "reports" is just the name of the channel where the bot will send the message

Comment: Pls, can you tell me on what line is the error, because you have there more send() functions.

Comment: The same as above. The error message is pretty straightforward, you want to check the object on which you call send, on the line specified in the error message

Comment: Yes sorry, the problem is in the last string, rChannel.send(reportEmbed)

Comment: @MattTheDragon, did you try console.log(rChannel)?

Comment: @szeb The error message says that rChannel is not defined, but iI defined it in the string
`let rChannel = client.channels.cache.get(707956253040574525)`
I watched some videos and watched around some forums or sites, everybody uses this code, but with me it doesn't wotk

Comment: @doc. Chocholoušek, with console.log(rChannel) gives me "fn is not a function" error

Comment: @MattTheDragon it might be that rChannel is declared, then your ...cache.get() function returns undefined. It might be that the number that it recieves as a parameter is not valid

Comment: @szeb How can i declear rChannel without .chache.get()?

Comment: @MattTheDragon just by writing 'let rChannel' you are already declaring it. But it seems to me that you want to use 'client.channels.cache.get' here, the point I am trying to make is that even though you call the function, it might not be called with the right parameter and it seems to me it returns 'undefined'

Comment: @szeb If I declear rChannel as `let rChannel = 707956253040574525` or `let rChannel = '707956253040574525'`, I can't still use the function .send, I would just like to send the bot a message in a channel specified by me

Comment: @MattTheDragon, this is because the id is just string, and you need to get the channel object, but when you do .cache.get(id), it can still return undefinied, becuase the bot can have cached no channel with this id. So it will help to know what is the value of rChannel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update Node.js.

Discord.js v12 requires Node.js 12.0.0+.

To update Node.js run the following in your terminal:

```
npm install -g npm stable

npm install -g node
```

Comment: I've upgraded node.js, but it still gives an error, but this time is "TypeError: fn.bind is not a function", I don't know how to solve this

Comment: Did you make sure it actually upgraded? what's your node version now?

Comment: if I type "node -v" in the command prompt it tells me that the version is the 12.16.2

Comment: At the moment, how are you defining `rChannel`?

Comment: `let rChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(\`name\`, 'reports')`

Comment: That's your issue then, you need to use a function inside the `find()` method: `let rChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'reports')`